# print array values separately

Tags: php

I have created an array in php that prints this

```
Array ( [mark] => Array ( [0] => 3 [1] => 4 ) )
```

How i can print the marks separately from the array. e.g just print out 3.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming `$array` is your array:

```
echo $array['mark'][0];
```

Answer (score 1):

to print all values:

```
foreach($array as $value){
 echo $value."<br />";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$myArray = array('mark'=>array(3, 4));
```

You can print a specific element by using for example:

```
echo $myArray['mark'][0]; // this would print out 3
```

You could also loop through the array:

```
foreach($myArray['mark'] => $item) {
    echo $item;
}

// this would result it the printing of 3 first and then 4
```